# Search by filters using views in CouchDB

Tags: view, couchdb

I have a CouchDB database where I store models like this:

```
"_id": "id",
"_rev": "rev",
"field_1": "test",
"filed_2": 45,
"filed_3": 15,
"object_1": {
  "field_1_1": 123,
  "filed_1_2": 125
  }
}
```

And I want to search for models by specific parameters in different ranges (filters).

For example, in one situation I need to find all the models with

- field_2 from 10 to 50
- field_3 from 10 to 20
- object_1.field_1_1 from 100 to 150, object_1.field_1_2 from 120 to 130

In another case I need to find just all the models with field_2 from 10 to 50.

At the moment I wrote view like this:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.filed_2, doc.field_3, doc.object_1.field_1_1, doc.object_1.filed_1_2], 1);
}
```

So it generates that result:

```
{"id":"id","key":[45,15,123, 125],"value":1}
```

I can use this array-key to fetch necessary models and I can use "startkey" and "endkey" to generate ranges.

But Is there more efficient way to create search by different filters (some filters can be skipped, user selects the filters he wants to search by) in CouchDB? How Can I combine different parameters?

And How Can I skip parameters if they were not chosen for search (like in the second case)?

Thank you.

Comment: Which couchdb version are you using?

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

In CouchDB 2.x you can use the /db/_find endpoint with Mango expressions in order to query the database.

Please, check the [expression syntax](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/database/find.html#find-selectors) in order to check if it can cover your needs.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it and reply later. Thank you.